# Public Key signing/verification

Tags: public-key-encryption, pki

I'm developing an application to manage file and email encryption using (primarily) PKI. I have a Public Keyring with a list of contacts and their Public Keys.

Referring back to the olden days when I used PGP, I recall a requirement to sign public keys with your Private Key.

Is this a necessity on PKI and if so, what does this signing achieve? Is it bad practice to simply hold a list/database of people's names (and email) and their Public Key? Surely if their public key is - in any way - tampered with the encryption would fail and as you choose who you're sending or sharing the encrypted data with, even if a 'successful tamper' went unnoticed, the encrypted data wouldn't end up in the wrong hands anyway?

Comment: How do you know that the public key you got in the first place is correct?

Comment: OK, good point. So how does signing it prove otherwise? Say you generate a key pair, sent me your public key, and I store this. How can I prove this is a valid key?

Comment: The people who sign it (hopefully) verify the owner.

Comment: So in my above example, I know you so I sign your public key? This proves it is YOUR key? Is it a necessity to sign every public key on your keychain or is it just a 'nice' feature? I suppose I am asking, can you legitimately use the that public key for securing data even if it hasn't been signed? So I've never met you but I want to send you secure data - is it still 'safe' to do so?

Comment: It all depends on what you're trying to secure the data against.  Also, knowing me is not enough; you need to confirm that no MITM attacker has modified the key you think is mine.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signing_party

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible for you to securely send me data unless I have some out-of-band way to verify that you ware who you claim to be.  (eg, trusted third party)  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: ^^ That was a very interesting read! Made perfect sense even at 4am! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole thing about signing a public key with a private key is useful when you have a dedicated key-pair that you use only for signing, and then other key-pairs that you use for encrypting.  This dedicated key-pair is your "trusted" key-pair that is somehow known to be legitimately attached to you (often by having it signed by a certificate authority or by having many trusted people sign that they have verified it's connection to you.)

You use this "trusted" private key to sign your not-quite-as-trusted public key.  This way, people can un-sign/decrypt your new public-key with your trusted public-key.  This is only mathematically possible if it was signed by your trusted private-key.

This process helps people to be sure that this new public-key actually belongs to you.